# Array Overflow Check

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm trying to check whether or not an array is overflowing.
This is the logic that I'm using:

```
/*
        store the length of the stackArray[] into a temp. int.
        compare the size of the temp int to the stackArray[] via 3 tests.
        
        If the stackArray[]'s size is greater than the int's size,
            then say that the array is overflowing, and that it doesn't have any more space to enter elements into.
        If the stackArray[]'s size is less than the int's size,
            then say that the stackArray[] is underflowing and that it still has space to enter some elements into it.
        If the stackArray[]'s size is equal to the int's size,
            then say that the array is full.
*/
```

To implement this logic, here's the method I'm using:

```
public void overflowCheck(int temp)
{
    if(stackArraySize/stackArray.length > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("stack is overflowing");
    }
    else if(stackArraySize/stackArray.length < 100)
    {
       System.out.println("stack is not full");
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("stack is full");
    }
}
```

But when I run this on my array, I keep getting *"stack is not full*. Here's my array:

```
Data stackTest = new Data(10, false); //create a new stack & confirm it's not a queue
int stackSize = stackTest.size;
stackTest.push(10); //push 10 into the stack
stackTest.push(20); //push 20 into the stack
stackTest.push(30); //push 30 into the stack
stackTest.push(40); //push 40 into the stack
stackTest.push(50); //push 50 into the stack
stackTest.push(60); //push 60 into the stack
stackTest.push(70); //push 70 into the stack
stackTest.push(80); //push 80 into the stack
stackTest.push(90); //push 90 into the stack
stackTest.push(100); //push 100 into the stack
stackTest.push(110); //push 110 into the stack
stackTest.push(120); //push 120 into the stack

stackTest.overflowCheck(stackSize);
```

I should be getting an output of "stack is overflowing", but I keep getting "stack is not full".

Is this because my logic is flawed or my execution is flawed?
How do I fix this?

*full class*

```
    int size; //initialize size
    int stackArray[]; //initialize array
    int top; //initialize top
    int stackArraySize;
    public Data(int size, boolean isArrayQueue) //constructor
    {
        if(isArrayQueue)
        {
            len = 0;
            Queue = new int[size];
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.size = size;
            this.stackArray = new int[size];
            this.top = -1;
        }
    }
public boolean isFull() //check if it's full
    {
        return(size-1 == top);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() //check if it's empty
    {
        return(top == -1);
    }
    public void push(int pushedElement) //push an element into the stack, as long as isFull is false
    {
        if(!isFull()) //check if the stack is already full
        {
            top++; //increment top
            stackArray[top] = pushedElement; //set array[top] to the pushedElement
            System.out.println("The pushed element is: " + pushedElement);
        }
        else //if the stack is full, tell the user.
        {
            System.out.println("The stack is full.");
        }
    }
    public int pop() //pop an element from the stack, as long as isEmpty is false
    {
        if(!isEmpty()) //check is the stack is already empty.
        {
            int originalTop = top; //store original top value into originalTop
            top--;//decrement top
            System.out.println("The popped element is: " + stackArray[originalTop]);
            return stackArray[originalTop]; //return the originalTop again
        }
        else //if the stack is empty, tell the user.
        {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public int top() //peek into the stack & return the element on the top
    {
        if(!this.isEmpty()) //if the stack has values, return the top element.
        {
            return stackArray[top];
        }
        else //if the stack is empty, tell the user.
        {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you mean to check < 1 ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case if I used modulus instead of divide?

Comment: yes. I set StackArraySize to temp.

Comment: How is your Data class implemented and why are you passing the size of array to check the overflow. Size of array will always be same.

Comment: I'm using the Data class as an object center where I create objects to run other classes on. I'm passing the size of the array to check if the # of elements I put into the stackArray is greater than that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ratio to check needs it to be a double, otherwise typecast would keep it as default integer.

Having said that, your `push` method does not currently allow for elements to be pushed after length defined, which you would need for the below `overflowCheck` to work.

```
class StackCheck {
    Data stackTest = new Data(10, false); //create a new stack & confirm it's not a queue
    public static void main() {
    
        stackTest.push(10); //push 10 into the stack
        stackTest.push(20); //push 20 into the stack
        stackTest.push(30); //push 30 into the stack
        stackTest.push(40); //push 40 into the stack
        stackTest.push(50); //push 50 into the stack
        stackTest.push(60); //push 60 into the stack
        stackTest.push(70); //push 70 into the stack
        stackTest.push(80); //push 80 into the stack
        stackTest.push(90); //push 90 into the stack
        stackTest.push(100); //push 100 into the stack
        stackTest.push(110); //push 110 into the stack
        stackTest.push(120); //push 120 into the stack

        stackTest.overflowCheck();
    }
    public void overflowCheck() {   
        double ratio = stackArray.length/stackTest.size;
        if(ratio > 1){
            System.out.println("stack is overflowing");
        }
        else if(ratio == 1){
           System.out.println("stack is full");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("stack is not full");
        }
   
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to modified your logic and update the value of stackArraySize in push and pop method you are not updating this value anywhere

```
public class Data {

    int size; // initialize size
    int stackArray[]; // initialize array
    int top; // initialize top
    int stackArraySize;
    int len;
    int[] Queue;
    int front;
    int rear;

    public Data(int size, boolean isArrayQueue) // constructor
    {
        if (isArrayQueue) {
            len = 0;
            Queue = new int[size];
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;
        } else {
            this.size = size;
            this.stackArray = new int[size];
            this.top = -1;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull() // check if it's full
    {
        return (size - 1 == top);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() // check if it's empty
    {
        return (top == -1);
    }

    public void push(int pushedElement) // push an element into the stack, as
                                        // long as isFull is false
    {
        
        
        if (!isFull()) // check if the stack is already full
        {
            top++; // increment top
            stackArray[top] = pushedElement; // set array[top] to the
            stackArraySize=top;                 // pushedElement
            System.out.println("The pushed element is: " + pushedElement);
        } else // if the stack is full, tell the user.
        {
            stackArraySize++;
            System.out.println("The stack is full.");
        }
    }

    public int pop() // pop an element from the stack, as long as isEmpty is
                        // false
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) // check is the stack is already empty.
        {
            int originalTop = top; // store original top value into originalTop
            top--;// decrement top
            System.out.println("The popped element is: " + stackArray[originalTop]);
            stackArraySize=top; 
            return stackArray[originalTop]; // return the originalTop again
        } else // if the stack is empty, tell the user.
        {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public int top() // peek into the stack & return the element on the top
    {
        if (!this.isEmpty()) // if the stack has values, return the top element.
        {
            return stackArray[top];
        } else // if the stack is empty, tell the user.
        {
            System.out.println("The stack is empty");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void overflowCheck(int temp) {
        if (stackArraySize>= temp) {
            System.out.println("stack is overflowing");
        } else if (stackArraySize<temp) {
            System.out.println("stack is not full");
        } else {
            System.out.println("stack is full");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Data stackTest = new Data(10, false); // create a new stack & confirm
                                                // it's not a queue
        int stackSize = stackTest.size;
        stackTest.push(10); // push 10 into the stack
        stackTest.push(20); // push 20 into the stack
        stackTest.push(30); // push 30 into the stack
        stackTest.push(40); // push 40 into the stack
        stackTest.push(50); // push 50 into the stack
        stackTest.push(60); // push 60 into the stack
        stackTest.push(70); // push 70 into the stack
        stackTest.push(80); // push 80 into the stack
        stackTest.push(90); // push 90 into the stack
        stackTest.push(100); // push 100 into the stack
        stackTest.push(110); // push 110 into the stack
        stackTest.push(120); // push 120 into the stack

        stackTest.overflowCheck(stackSize);
        
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop();
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.pop(); 
        stackTest.overflowCheck(stackSize);
    }

}
```

Comment: I set stackArraySize to temp, & then set stackArraySize to stackArray.length, & then ran the method to compare stackArraySize to temp. Now I keep getting "stack is overflowing"

Comment: as per your dataset stackSize is 12 so your are passing as 12 .so temp=12 you have to compare this temp against your array size if arraysize<temp then overflow because you can not add anymore item if arraysize>temp the underflow you can add  now you decide which variable is taking size off array in my code size of array is stackArraySize

Comment: Please paste you entire class otherwise will make assumption which might not help you if its working well and good

Comment: edited the post you need to updated the stackArraySize value in push and pop